# Problem with XML parsing using jQuery

Tags: jquery

The code here is supposed to place Random images from an XML file into layers. It works but only display the first image in the XML instead of taking Random nodes out of the XML file. Does anyone know why this is?

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "myFakeChannelData.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: changeChannel
    });
});

function changeChannel(xml) {
    $('#layer').fadeOut(1000);
    var $limit = 4;
    $(xml).find("Channel").each(function($limit) {  
        var $channel = $(this);
        var image = $channel.attr('image');
        $("#click").click(function () {
            $(".layer-container").empty();
                $(".layer-container").append('<div class="layer1">' + 
            '<img class="" alt=""   src="' + image + '" />' +  '</div></div>');
            $(".layer-container").append('<div class="layer2">' + '<img class=""                     alt=""  src="' + image + '" />' +  '</div></div>');
             $(".layer-container").append('<div class="layer3">' + '<img class="" alt=""    src="' +     image + '" />' +  '</div></div>');
            $(".Channel").fadeIn(1000);
            var random = Math.floor(limit * Math.random());
            var myNewChannel = remix(random);
            myNewChannel(random);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because of this typo: `Math.floor(limit * Math.random());`
instead of `Math.floor($limit * Math.random());`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of that?
**var random = Math.floor($limit * Math.random());**

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myFakeChannelData.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: changeChannel
    });
});

function changeChannel(xml) {
    $('#layer').fadeOut(1000);
    var $limit = 4;
    $(xml).find("Channel").each(function($limit) {
        var $channel = $(this);
        var image = $channel.attr('image');
        $("#click").click(function() {
            $(".layer-container").empty();
            $(".layer-container").append('<div class="layer1">' + '<img class="" alt=""   src="' + image + '" />' + '</div></div>');
            $(".layer-container").append('<div class="layer2">' + '<img class=""                     alt=""  src="' + image + '" />' + '</div></div>');
            $(".layer-container").append('<div class="layer3">' + '<img class="" alt=""    src="' + image + '" />' + '</div></div>');
            $(".Channel").fadeIn(1000);
            var random = Math.floor($limit * Math.random());
            var myNewChannel = remix(random);
            myNewChannel(random);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Tried changing it. It still does the same thing.